# scalaz using reduceLeft for applicative builder

Tags: validation, scala, scalaz, applicative

I am little confused about |@| magic in scalaz. Here is my code:

```
def isThree(x: Int): Validation[NonEmptyList[String], Int] = if (x!= 3){("failed: %d" format x).wrapNel.failure} else {x.success}

println((isThree(6) |@| isThree(7) |@| isThree(13) ) {_ + _ + _})
```

**output**: Failure(NonEmptyList(failed: 6, failed: 7, failed: 13))
This is output is what I want.

**Here is my questions:**

1. assume I have sequence of Validation, I want to use applicative builder to chain them together.

   Seq(isThree(13), isThree(15)).reduceLeft(_ |@| _)
   why compilation failed due to type not matching ?
2. It is similar to first question, if I use **bracket** :

   `println((isThree(6) |@| (sThree(7) |@| isThree(13)) ) {_ + _ + _})`, it still has compilation errors.

Also, I know I can fix the first one by using <* instead of |@|, but I am still confused why is that, it looks not convenient to use.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice to know what exact error message you get. In your 2. you have a typo. `sThree(7)`

Comment: Is there some reason you want to use the applicative builder syntax instead of just `vals.sequenceU.map(_.sum)` or `vals.suml`?

Comment: Or even `List(6, 7, 13).traverseU(isThree).map(_.sum)`, which may be better than building up the list of validations in the first place.

Comment: That is a good idea, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works: |@| result type is not ValidationNel (Applicative) but ApplicativeBuilder, you need yo apply it first to some function

```
  import scalaz._, Scalaz._

  val x1: ValidationNel[String, Int] = 1.successNel
  val x2: ValidationNel[String, Int] = 2.successNel
  val x3: ValidationNel[String, Int] = 3.successNel

  println((x1 |@| x2 |@| x3)(_ + _ + _))

  println((x1 :: x2 :: x3 :: Nil).reduceLeft((l, r) => (l |@| r)(_ + _)))
```